# Is it appropriate to answer a question that is tagged to a specific language version while my answer uses a newer API?

Tags: discussion, answers

Imagine a situation:

there is a good question that is tagged to a specific language version (for example: [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8)) with good answers. At the same time, there is a new API method in the newer version of the language (for example, in [java-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-9)), that certainly can be used in order to solve a problem!

Is it appropriate from my side to answer the question with an example that uses a newer API?

I didn't find any similar questions and I think it is a good canonical question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Yes. Maybe.

There is everything wrong with providing an answer that uses a functionality only available in a newer API, if the question is tagged with a specific version.

People (are supposed to) [use version-specific tags because they're stuck with that version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80039/tagging-best-practices), or because they have a question about functionality introduced with that version.

So yeah you can come and barge in and answer *"Using version N+M you can foo the bar"*, but that won't help the OP nor later visitors who also are stuck on version N.

So if you must, you should also mention very explicitly that you don't know how, or that you do know how you can't, do X with version N, but that if the reader can upgrade to version N+M, they could do it in the way you then describe in your answer.

When a new language, framework or library version introduces commonly discussed or requested features, that's better posted as an answer to a generic, version-unspecific question asking about said feature.

See for example [C# variables in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227413/c-sharp-variables-in-strings)

Comment: Of course I agree with you! But I'd like to emphasize that the question is a good canonical question, and it also includes a tag with specific language version. Specifically `java, java-8, ...`

Comment: If it's a canonical, then the version-specific tag should be reconsidered.

Comment: @CodeCaster or a new canonical question should be written, prominently linking to the old one and emphasizing that it is for the new version. Or an existing answer amended to mention the new solution, too. There doesn't seem to be a one-size-fits-all solution, whatever will be more readable in the particular case seems to be used.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it appropriate from my side to answer the question with an example that uses a newer API?

The Simple answer is **YES** you can provide your answer using newer api

There is nothing wrong if you provide answer using newer api

But make sure you provide necessary information  about newer api in your answer